# Swift: Find all occurrences of a substring

Tags: swift, string

I have an extension of the `String` class in Swift that returns the index of the first letter of a given substring.

Can anybody please help me make it so it will return an array of all occurrences instead of just the first one?

```
extension String {
    func indexOf(string : String) -> Int {
        var index = -1
        if let range = self.range(of : string) {
            if !range.isEmpty {
                index = distance(from : self.startIndex, to : range.lowerBound)
            }
        }
        return index
    }
}
```

For example instead of a return value of `50` I would like something like `[50, 74, 91, 103]`

Comment: Sentinel values like `-1` have no place in Swift. This is what optionals are for.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You just keep advancing the search range until you can't find any more instances of the substring:

```
extension String {
    func indicesOf(string: String) -> [Int] {
        var indices = [Int]()
        var searchStartIndex = self.startIndex

        while searchStartIndex < self.endIndex,
            let range = self.range(of: string, range: searchStartIndex..<self.endIndex),
            !range.isEmpty
        {
            let index = distance(from: self.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
            indices.append(index)
            searchStartIndex = range.upperBound
        }

        return indices
    }
}

let keyword = "a"
let html = "aaaa"
let indicies = html.indicesOf(string: keyword)
print(indicies) // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `while let`. brilliant.

Comment: Hmm. This seems to fail.         `let keyword = "hello"
let html = "<html><head><title>My Website</title></head><body>hello</body>hello</html>hello"
let indicies = html.indicesOf(string: keyword)
print(indicies)`    `fatal error: cannot increment beyond endIndex`

Comment: It seems like it doesn't like things at the end of the string. It looks really good so far though.

Comment: A more simplified example: `let keyword = "a"
let html = "a"
let indicies = html.indicesOf(string: keyword)
print(indicies)`     `fatal error: cannot increment beyond endIndex`

Comment: If you put two of the same keyword in a row it will only find one. It finds two if you put three in a row though. Looking much better though.

Comment: It's another bug. The perils of insufficient testing. Updated again

Comment: It doesn't work always if the length of the keyword is > 1, e.g. keyword="aba", html="ababa", result=[0] but it should be [0, 2] instead. That happens because of: searchStartIndex = range.upperBound

Comment: @Eugenio if you allow substrings to overlap, advance the search start index one character at a time: `searchStartIndex = string.index(after: searchStartIndex)`

Answer (score 10):

I know we aren't playing code golf here, but for anyone interested in a functional style one-line implementation that doesn't use `var`s or loops, this is another possible solution:

```
extension String {
    func indices(of string: String) -> [Int] {
        return indices.reduce([]) { $1.encodedOffset > ($0.last ?? -1) && self[$1...].hasPrefix(string) ? $0 + [$1.encodedOffset] : $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.encodedOffset` is deprecated, use `.utf16Offset(in: self)` instead

Answer (score 8):

Here are 2 functions. One returns `[Range<String.Index>]`, the other returns `[Range<Int>]`. If you don't need the former, you can make it private. I've designed it to mimic the `range(of:options:range:locale:)` method, so it supports all the same features.

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    public func allRanges(
        of aString: String,
        options: String.CompareOptions = [],
        range: Range<String.Index>? = nil,
        locale: Locale? = nil
    ) -> [Range<String.Index>] {

        // the slice within which to search
        let slice = (range == nil) ? self[...] : self[range!]

        var previousEnd = s.startIndex
        var ranges = [Range<String.Index>]()

        while let r = slice.range(
            of: aString, options: options,
            range: previousEnd ..< s.endIndex,
            locale: locale
        ) {
            if previousEnd != self.endIndex { // don't increment past the end
                    previousEnd = self.index(after: r.lowerBound)
            }
            ranges.append(r)
        }

        return ranges
    }

    public func allRanges(
        of aString: String,
        options: String.CompareOptions = [],
        range: Range<String.Index>? = nil,
        locale: Locale? = nil
    ) -> [Range<Int>] {
        return allRanges(of: aString, options: options, range: range, locale: locale)
            .map(indexRangeToIntRange)
    }


    private func indexRangeToIntRange(_ range: Range<String.Index>) -> Range<Int> {
        return indexToInt(range.lowerBound) ..< indexToInt(range.upperBound)
    }

    private func indexToInt(_ index: String.Index) -> Int {
        return self.distance(from: self.startIndex, to: index)
    }
}

let s = "abc abc  abc   abc    abc"
print(s.allRanges(of: "abc") as [Range<String.Index>])
print()
print(s.allRanges(of: "abc") as [Range<Int>])
```

Comment: Works great for ranges. I was looking for integers for my purpose but it is definitely helpful to most.

Comment: @Alexander you have `s.startIndex` and `s.endIndex`, i believe they're meant to be `slice.startIndex` and `slice.endIndex`?

Comment: +1 On this answer. Int indexes are easier to understand, but they generally result in less performant code. eg: a range of `String.Index` allows you to take a substring like `let r = s[range]` which is more convenient as well as faster than indexing the string using Int's.

Comment: This line gives an error: let slice = (range == nil) ? self : self[range!]  .. and the error is: Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent

Comment: @Starwave This is really old code, I haven't been maintaining it.

Answer (score 7):

There's not really a built-in function to do this, but we can implement a modified [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to get all the indices of the string we want to match. It should also be very performant as we don't need to repeatedly call **range** on the string.

```
extension String {
    func indicesOf(string: String) -> [Int] {
        // Converting to an array of utf8 characters makes indicing and comparing a lot easier
        let search = self.utf8.map { $0 }
        let word = string.utf8.map { $0 }

        var indices = [Int]()

        // m - the beginning of the current match in the search string
        // i - the position of the current character in the string we're trying to match
        var m = 0, i = 0
        while m + i < search.count {
            if word[i] == search[m+i] {
                if i == word.count - 1 {
                    indices.append(m)
                    m += i + 1
                    i = 0
                } else {
                    i += 1
                }
            } else {
                m += 1
                i = 0
            }
        }

        return indices
    }
}
```

Comment: Oooo very nice, I appreciate that you implemented this yourself. `we don't need to repeatedly call range on the string` that's probably fine, most likely `range` just does KMP search, as well.

Comment: This is great! One little shortcoming I noticed: if you pass in a string of 0 length, you hit a crash - want me to suggest a fix?

Comment: Some advice. Just want to point out that Swift has terrible optimisation of array collections, and this method is far better of using C/ObjC for performant reasons. As of yet, I have not seen anything that Swift does natively be performant.

Comment: This needs a bit of rewriting as C writing is not supported anymore

Comment: How to make case insestive search ?

Answer (score 4):

Please check the following answer for finding multiple items in multiple locations

```
func indicesOf(string: String) -> [Int] {
    var indices = [Int]()
    var searchStartIndex = self.startIndex
    
    while searchStartIndex < self.endIndex,
        let range = self.range(of: string, range: searchStartIndex..<self.endIndex),
        !range.isEmpty
    {
        let index = distance(from: self.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
        indices.append(index)
        searchStartIndex = range.upperBound
    }
    
    return indices
}

func attributedStringWithColor(_ strings: [String], color: UIColor, characterSpacing: UInt? = nil) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    for string in strings {
        let indexes = self.indicesOf(string: string)
        for index in indexes {
            let range = NSRange(location: index, length: string.count)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: color, range: range)
        }
    }
    
    guard let characterSpacing = characterSpacing else {return attributedString}
    
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: characterSpacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
    
    return attributedString
}
```

can be used as follows :

```
let message = "Item 1 + Item 2 + Item 3"
message.attributedStringWithColor(["Item", "+"], color: UIColor.red)
```

and gets the result [image]

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.7+ ( iOS 16.0+ | macOS 13.0+ )**

Swift's `Foundation` has now [`ranges(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/ranges(of:)/), which does the job of finding all occurences:

```
extension String {
    func allIndices(of subString: String, caseSensitive: Bool = true) -> [Int] {
        if caseSensitive {
            return self.ranges(of: subString).map { distance(from: self.startIndex, to: $0.lowerBound) }
        } else {
            return self.lowercased().ranges(of: subString.lowercased()).map { distance(from: self.startIndex, to: $0.lowerBound) }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with recursive method. I used a numeric string to test it. It returns an optional array of `Int`, meaning it will be nil if no substring can be found.

```
extension String {
    func indexes(of string: String, offset: Int = 0) -> [Int]? {
        if let range = self.range(of : string) {
            if !range.isEmpty {
                let index = distance(from : self.startIndex, to : range.lowerBound) + offset
                var result = [index]
                let substr = self.substring(from: range.upperBound)
                if let substrIndexes = substr.indexes(of: string, offset: index + distance(from: range.lowerBound, to: range.upperBound)) {
                    result.append(contentsOf: substrIndexes)
                }
                return result
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let numericString = "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
numericString.indexes(of: "3456")
```

Comment: Theres no need for this to be recursive. It's just an unnecessary memory hit.

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked the accepted answer so that `case sensitivity` can be configured

```
extension String {
    func allIndexes(of subString: String, caseSensitive: Bool = true) -> [Int] {
        let subString = caseSensitive ? subString : subString.lowercased()
        let mainString = caseSensitive ? self : self.lowercased()
        var indices = [Int]()
        var searchStartIndex = mainString.startIndex
        while searchStartIndex < mainString.endIndex,
            let range = mainString.range(of: subString, range: searchStartIndex..<mainString.endIndex),
            !range.isEmpty
        {
            let index = distance(from: mainString.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
            indices.append(index)
            searchStartIndex = range.upperBound
        }

        return indices
    }
}
```