# Swift Regex doesn't work

Tags: regex, swift

I am using the following extension method to get NSRange array of a substring:

```
extension String {
  func nsRangesOfString(findStr:String) -> [NSRange] {
    let ranges: [NSRange]
    do {
      // Create the regular expression.
      let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: findStr, options: [])

      // Use the regular expression to get an array of NSTextCheckingResult.
      // Use map to extract the range from each result.
      ranges = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)).map {$0.range}
    }
    catch {
      // There was a problem creating the regular expression
      ranges = []
    }
    return ranges
  }
}
```

However, I didn't realize why it doesn't work sometimes. Here are two similar cases, one works and the other doesn't:

That one works:

self(String):

> "וצפן (קרי: יִצְפֹּ֣ן) לַ֭יְשָׁרִים תּוּשִׁיָּ֑ה מָ֝גֵ֗ן לְהֹ֣לְכֵי תֹֽם׃"

findStr:

> "קרי:"

And that one doesn't:

self(String):

> "לִ֭נְצֹר אָרְח֣וֹת מִשְׁפָּ֑ט וְדֶ֖רֶךְ חסידו (קרי: חֲסִידָ֣יו) יִשְׁמֹֽר׃"

findStr:

> "קרי:"

(An alternate steady method would be an appropriate answer though.)

Comment: I'm sorry but would you kindly convert sample strings to English?

Comment: I could, but those aren't just random strings, those are the real strings being matched in my app, and i want to figure out why the second returns nothing.

Comment: is it mandatory to use regex to do such a task?

Comment: Negative. Another suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do here? What is the end goal? Happy to suggest another way but I don’t know what your requirement is for this.

Comment: I am locating special pieces in strings and formatting their ranges specially (size, color) in attributed strings.

Comment: See if this might be helpful if not with regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413218/swift-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSRange` ranges are specified in terms of UTF-16 code units (which
is what `NSString` uses internally), therefore the length must be
`self.utf16.count`:

```
        ranges = regex.matches(in: self, options: [],
                               range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count))
            .map {$0.range}
```

In the case of your second string we have

```
let s2 = "לִ֭נְצֹר אָרְח֣וֹת מִשְׁפָּ֑ט וְדֶ֖רֶךְ חסידו (קרי: חֲסִידָ֣יו) יִשְׁמֹֽר׃"
print(s2.characters.count) // 46
print(s2.utf16.count)      // 74
```

and that's why the pattern is not found with your code.

Starting with **Swift 4** you can compute a `NSRange` for the entire string also as

```
NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self)
```

Comment: Also possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches.

Comment: Awesome. Is it safe to use `utf16.count` for all other types of string (including English)?

Comment: @sCha: `s.utf16.count` is the number of UTF-16 code units in a string, and always the same as `(s as NSString).length`, no matter what language. *If* you need a NSRange/NSString compatible count then that's the correct method.