# Using NSRegularExpression produces incorrect ranges when emoji are present

Tags: ios, swift, string, emoji

I'm trying to parse out "@mentions" from a user provided string. The regular expression itself seems to find them, but the range it provides is incorrect when emoji are present.

```
let text = " @joe "
let tagExpr = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@\\S+")
tagExpr?.enumerateMatches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count)) { tag, flags, pointer in
    guard let tag = tag?.range else { return }

    if let newRange = Range(tag, in: text) {
        let replaced = text.replacingCharacters(in: newRange, with: "[email]")
        print(replaced)
    }
}
```

When running this
`tag` = (location: 7, length: 2)

And prints out
 `[email]oe`

The expected result is
 `[email]`

Comment: Use an NSString with NSRegularExpressions when you need an NSRange - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39701370/3937

Comment: `text.characters.count` must be `text.utf16.count` for an NSRange.

Answer (score 8):

`NSRegularExpression` (and anything involving `NSRange`) operates on UTF16 counts / indexes. For that matter, `NSString.count` is the UTF16 count as well.

But in your code, you're telling `NSRegularExpression` to use a length of `text.characters.count`. This is the number of composed characters, not the UTF16 count. Your string `" @joe "` has 9 composed characters, but 12 UTF16 code units. So you're actually telling `NSRegularExpression` to only look at the first 9 UTF16 code units, which means it's ignoring the trailing `"oe "`.

The fix is to pass `length: text.utf16.count`.

```
let text = " @joe "
let tagExpr = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "@\\S+")
tagExpr?.enumerateMatches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count)) { tag, flags, pointer in
    guard let tag = tag?.range else { return }

    if let newRange = Range(tag, in: text) {
        let replaced = text.replacingCharacters(in: newRange, with: "[email]")
        print(replaced)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what was answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293204/swift-regex-doesnt-work , and therefore I closed as a duplicate of *that one*. Not sure why that should be a "bad dupe" and reopened.

Comment: @MartinR Did the dupe change? I clicked through to the duplicate and it was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701316/use-regex-to-match-emojis-as-well-as-text-in-string/39701370#39701370, which was an answer recommending going through `NSString`.

Comment: Hmm, that link I provided is actually in the comments on the post. Did I simply misclick? Argh.

Comment: That was a comment from Lou Franco, but not what I chose as  a duplicate.

Comment: I've re-duped it. Sorry about that.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when I try to retrieve the matched substring. If an emoji precedes it `text[range]` will be one character offset.

Comment: it doesn't work either. Do we know a good solution? thanks