# There is a regex for email validation in java that works perfectly in android. Can someone help me convert it to swift?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

The regex in kotlin does not allow white spaces, emojis etc. I want this regex to be used in swift but the regex does not work exactly and needs to be converted. I have tried but I am unable to achieve proper conversion. Help would be appreciated

Code tested in online kotlin playground

**Kotlin Playground code:**

```
import java.util.regex.*

fun main() {

    println(isValidEmailAddress(" abc@gmail.com"))
    // returns false
    println(isValidEmailAddress("abc@gmail.com"))
    // returns false

}

val EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
            "\\@" +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
            "(" +
                "\\." +
                "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
            ")+")

public fun isValidEmailAddress(email: String): Boolean {
        return EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches()
    }
```

Code tested in online swift playground

**Swift Playground code:**

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-+]{1,256}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25}+", options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count)) != nil
    }
}

var str = " abc@gmail.com".isValidEmail()
print(str)
// returns true
str = "abc@gmail.com".isValidEmail()
print(str)
// returns true
```

**Answer after following suggested changes:**

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-]{1,256}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25})+$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count)) != nil
    }
}

var str = " abcgmail.com".isValidEmail()
print(str)
// returns false
str = "ac@gmail.com".isValidEmail()
print(str)
// returns false
```

Comment: For  a starter, using a string's `count` in `NSRange` is wrong and fails for emojis, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/46294637/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415.

Comment: The other error is that you have to anchor the pattern to the start and end of the string: `pattern: "^.....$"`

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for both the suggested changes. These solved the issue.

Comment: I think it's very likely that there's already a library available for Swift for this specific check.