# IOS How to get String.range(of:string) multiple in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsmutablestring

MyText is

```
let myString: NSAttributedString = <siren> 123123 <siren> 123123 <siren>
let myRange = myString.string.range(of:"<siren>")
let newString = NSMutableAttributedString()
newString.append(myString)
if myRange != nil{
  newString.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(myRange, in:myString.string), 
            with:myAttributeString as NSAttributedString!)
}
```

If `myString` has one `<siren>` this is worked, but it's not worked when it has more then two `<siren>`

replace only first `<siren>`

I think `String.range` return first value

how to find them all?

Comment: a) this isn't working code. b) don't start variables with uppercase letters, it makes it  hard to determine classes from variables. Please update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift find all occurrences of a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413218/swift-find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring)

Comment: Work with string then covert it to attributed string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find all ranges you can try to use solution from this question [get all ranges of a substring in a string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865443/get-all-ranges-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-swift)

but if your main purpose of that is replacing the occurrence of some string/pattern you can add an extension like that:

```
extension String {

  func replacing(pattern: String, withTemplate: String) throws -> String {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
    return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self,
                                          options: [],
                                          range: NSRange(0 ..< utf16.count),
                                          withTemplate: withTemplate)
  }
}
```